# Count no. of Rows on my Database table Between the selection of two Datetimepicker

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010

How can I get the total Rows of date records on my database between the selection of two datetimepicker? I don't have any idea how to do this. Had been searching for an answer for about an hour but I cannot find the correct code. Please help me.

Here's my code:

```
 Try
        ConnDB()

        If fromDate.Value > toDate.Value Then
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Date Selection", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
        Else
            sqlqry = "SELECT * FROM tblAttendance WHERE WorkingDate BETWEEN='" & fromDate.Value.ToShortDateString & "' AND '" & toDate.Value.ToShortDateString & "'"
            da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlqry, cnn)
            Dim dt As New DataTable("tblAttendance")
            da.Fill(dt)
            dgvAttendance.DataSource = dt
            Dim counter As Double
            counter = dt.Rows.Count
            TextBox1.Text = counter

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        If cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            cnn.Close()
        End If
    End Try
```

It only shows 0 value if I qoute as a comment this part of the code:

```
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlqry, cnn)
        Dim dt As New DataTable("tblAttendance")
        da.Fill(dt)
        dgvAttendance.DataSource = dt
```

Comment: Seems like you already do it: `dt.Rows.Count` what do you mean by having no idea? Anything unexpected?

Comment: It's not displaying the total number of rows, so I think I still have a problem on my code but it's not displaying any errors.

Comment: "Not displaying" - as in, showing `0`? Or there is no display at all?

Comment: Yes it only shows 0 value.

Comment: likely it is caused by the sql query you make, try to use parameterized query instead of `fromDate.Value.ToShortDateString` AND `toDate.Value.ToShortDateString` - it is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: As @Ian wrote please use a [parameterized query](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/26/parameter-queries-in-asp-net-with-ms-access). Converting a date into a string, pass it to access which then casts it back to a date is inconvenient.

Comment: @AlexB. I have tried to use a parameterized query, Between= d1 AND d2,  but nothing happens, still displaying 0 value.

Comment: `Between= d1 AND d2` is the wrong syntax. You have to use `Between ? and ?`

Answer (score 0):

You must format the string expressions of the date values to fit Access SQL:

```
sqlqry = "SELECT * FROM tblAttendance WHERE WorkingDate BETWEEN #" & fromDate.Value.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/dd") & "# AND #" & toDate.Value.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/dd") & "#"
```

or use parameters as already suggested.

Comment: I have tried paramerized query, using Between = ? AND ?, and tried the query that you have given, still not displaying total count within the date range. Is there any other solution/code how to get the total count of days within the date range I select on datetimepicker?

Comment: Oh, It's now workin, it seems that I just missed a Hash sign on my Query, while reading, it is said to be that on Access working on Date it must have a Hash sign. Thanks @Gustav

Comment: Yes, "seems", but that's only half the story.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out, Thanks for the help.

Here's my new code which really works.

```
Try
        ConnDB()

        If fromDate.Value > toDate.Value Then
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Date Selection", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
        Else
            sqlqry = "SELECT * FROM tblAttendance WHERE WorkingDate BETWEEN #" & fromDate.Value & "# AND #" & toDate.Value & "#"
            da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlqry, cnn)
            dt = New DataTable("tblAttendance")
            da.Fill(dt)
            Dim counter As Integer
            counter = dt.Rows.Count
            TextBox1.Text = counter

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        If cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            cnn.Close()
        End If
    End Try
```

Comment: No, it just appears to work. If you don't force a format on the date value, a default cast to string will be done when you concatenate it. That default format will fail in most non-US environments, thus you should always apply a format as I showed.